# Why does my for loop go out of bounds?

Tags: c, algorithm

I have a program to check if a sentence read on the keyboard is a [pangram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangram).

But when displaying the results (in the last `for`-loop), it goes out of the expected bounds. If you uncomment the `printf` statement, you can see that even thought `i<26` is set as the loop condition, it runs upto `i = 27` and the array of size 26 has elements `cache[26] = garbage value` and `cache[27] = 0`.  What is wrong with my last for loop ?

```
int main() {
    char* string = (char*)malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
    fgets(string, 1024, stdin);
    int i=0, cache[25]={0};
    while(string[i]!='\0' ){
        cache[(toupper(string[i])-'A')]++;
        i++;
    }
    for( i=0; i<26; i++){
       // printf("%d - %d\n",i,cache[i]);
        if(!cache[i]){
            printf("not pangram");
            return(0);
        }
    }
    printf("pangram");  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In C you do not need the cast for `malloc`

Comment: Do not access (no read nor write) out-of-rane of arrays!

Comment: @EdHeal unless you're in visual studio

Comment: What happens when a character is not a letter?

Comment: Change `cache[25]={0};` to `cache[26]={0};` and mind what @MikeCAT said.

Comment: @paulpaul1076 My `cl.exe` from VC++2008 accepted code without casting. No compiling C code as C++!

Comment: `cache[(toupper(string[i])-'A')]` may be out-of-range when `string[i] == '\n'`

Comment: @MikeCAT http://cs626431.vk.me/v626431318/364d/NVe6RnNDyuQ.jpg

Comment: @MikeCAT i guess that's c++ then. Didn't notice you said "no compiling as C++"

Comment: @paulpaul1076 Your file extension is `cpp`, so you are using C++.

Comment: [Don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your array is first too small for the 26 letters of the alphabet. It should be at least `cache[26]`.

Then the following might go out of range for any non alphabetic chars (comma, space, etc...):

```
cache[(toupper(string[i])-'A')]++;
```

Going out of range will corrupt your memory (for example overwrite i or whatever else can happen when the behavior is undefined).

**How to solve the issue?**

You may consider protecting your cache increment:

```
 if (isalpha(string[i]))
     cache[(toupper(string[i])-'A')]++;
```

Note that some more exotic locale might consider some chars outside the range 'A'-'Z' as being alpha.  So you may even want to be even stricter:

```
 int letter=toupper(string[i])-'A'; 
 if (letter>=0 && letter<26) 
     cache[(toupper(string[i])-'A')]++;
```